# Do we need to declare READ/WRITE permissions in manifest to access images from gallery and save them to app-specific Files storage(external)?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-storage

My apps requirement is to save images to app specific Files(External) folder. There are  Read/Write permissions currently given in manifest file. I read that we don't need any permissions to write into our app specific folder. But do I have to ask for  permission while we read images from intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT? Can I ged rid of READ permissions also from manifest?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No. For both you do not need any permission.

Comment: @blackapps I thought you have to specify read permission for the gallery, right? Dont need to declare permission for app-specific files is correct